# How to put into querySelector some IDs?

Tags: javascript

```
querySelector("#ID1, #ID2, ID#3")
```

Is there a possibility to put into one querySelector some IDs?

Comment: `ID#3` should be `#ID3`. Other than that, is there something unclear about the documentation on [`document.querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)? What isn’t working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

`querySelectorAll` can be used to target multiple selectors.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#div1, .div2, h3");
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple ! Use following code.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id1, #id2 , #id3');
```

This will return `nodelist` which you can iterate and can perform actions that you want.

Answer (score 2):

The `querySelector()` method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

Keep in mind that to return all the matches, use the `querySelectorAll()` method instead.

example

```
<div class="bar">.first </div>
<div class="bar">.second</div>
    
//get the first element with class bar
let firstElement = document.querySelector('.bar');
//log the first match
console.log(firstElement)

//get all elements with class bar
let allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.bar')
//You can use any common looping statement to access the matches
allElements.forEach(function(elements){
console.log(elements);
});
    /*
    querySelector("#ID1, #ID2, ID#3") 
    
    *select element matches #ID1 
    *select element matches #ID2
    *select element matches #ID3
    
    **/
//select  elements matches specified selectors #id1 , #id2 , #id3 and use any common looping statement to access them
let allMatchesId = document.querySelectorAll('#id1 , #id2 , #id3');
allMatchesId .forEach(function(elements){
console.log(elements);
});
```

read the docs here at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('#id1, #id2');
console.log(divs[0], divs[1]);
```

```html
<div id="id1"><div id="id2"></div></div>
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#:%7E:text=This%20example%20returns%20a%20list%20of%20all%20%3Cdiv%3E%20elements%20within%20the%20document%20with%20a%20class%20of%20either%20note%20or%20alert%3A)

Answer (score 0):

Just some more explanation:

This will work (if you correct the error `ID#3` instead of `#ID3`), however `querySelector` only returns the first element in the document that it matches (*NOT* the first ID in the list).

If you want all of the elements, then use `querySelectorAll`, but again the order of the elements will *NOT* be the order of the IDs, but the order of elements in the document. For example, given the following HTML:

```
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id1"></div>
```

then following JS:

```
 const divs = document.querySelectorAll("#id1, #id2");
 alert(divs[0].id); // This will show "id2"!
```